# MKR1010 disconnects and reconnects normally until it reaches a point where it never reconnects again

Tags: wifi, http, mkr1010

The board does reconnect from time to time, but there are times where it just disconnects and never reconnects again and I can't replicate the error because while I run it with Serial open and turn ON and OFF my WiFis it always reconnects as it should.

```cpp
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <EmonLib.h>

EnergyMonitor emon1;
EnergyMonitor emon2;
EnergyMonitor emon3;
int INTERVAL = 60;
int last_code = 0;

char ssid[] = "MySSID";
char pass[] = "MyPW";

String ID = "Garden_Pump_Sensor";

int sequence = 0;
double kWh = 0.0;

char serverAddress[] = "192.168.1.108";  // server address
int port = 5005;

WiFiClient wifi;
HttpClient client = HttpClient(wifi, serverAddress, port);

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogReadResolution(9);
  emon1.current(0, 100);
  emon2.current(5, 100);
  emon3.current(6, 100);
  Connecting();
}

void Connecting() {
  int tries = 4;
  while ( (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && tries > 0) || last_code != 200) {
    Serial.print("Status #1: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.status());
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    Serial.print("Status #2: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.status());
    tries--;
    last_code = 200;
  }

  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
}

void reconnecting() {
  if (WiFi.status() != 3  || (WiFi.RSSI() <= -90) || (WiFi.RSSI() == 0) || last_code != 200) {
    WiFi.end();
    Connecting();
  }
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long delayTime = INTERVAL * 1000;
  unsigned long time_start = millis();

  DataMonitorAndSend();

  unsigned long time_final = millis() - time_start;
  unsigned long delay_value = delayTime - time_final;
  Serial.println(delay_value);
  if (delay_value < 1  || delay_value > delayTime) {
    return;
  } else {
    delay(delay_value);
  }

}

void DataMonitorAndSend() {
  reconnecting();

  Serial.println("making POST request");
  String contentType = "application/json";
  kWh = kWh + getKWH();
  String postData = "{\"ID\": \""+ID+"\",\"seq\": " + String(sequence) + ",\"kWh\": " + String(kWh, 6) + "}";
  Serial.print("data: ");
  Serial.println(postData);

  client.setHttpResponseTimeout(5 * 1000);
  client.post("/receivedata/", contentType, postData);

  // read the status code and body of the response
  int statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();
  String response = client.responseBody();

  Serial.print("Status code: ");
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  if (statusCode == 200) {
    kWh = 0;
    sequence++;
  }
  last_code = statusCode;
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(response);


}

double getKWH() {
  int LOOPS = 15;
  double kWh_Total = 0.0;
  unsigned long delayTime_kwh = 2 * 1000;
  for (int i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
    unsigned long time_start_kwh = millis();

    double Irms1 = emon1.calcIrms(600);
    if (Irms1 < 0.3) Irms1 = 0;
    double Watt1 = (Irms1 * 230) / 1000;

    double Irms2 = emon2.calcIrms(600);
    if (Irms2 < 0.3) Irms2 = 0;
    double Watt2 = (Irms2 * 230) / 1000;

    double Irms3 = emon3.calcIrms(600);
    if (Irms3 < 0.3) Irms3 = 0;
    double Watt3 = (Irms3 * 230) / 1000;

    kWh_Total = kWh_Total + ((Watt1 + Watt2 + Watt3) / 60);

    unsigned long time_final_kwh = millis() - time_start_kwh;
    unsigned long delay_value_kwh = delayTime_kwh - time_final_kwh;
    if (delay_value_kwh < 0  || delay_value_kwh > delayTime_kwh) {
      delay(0);
    } else {
      delay(delay_value_kwh);
    }

  }

  return kWh_Total / LOOPS;
}
```

Feel free to ignore the `getkWH()`, it's code related to power consumption. Also the firmware is up to date and the server is using a static IP.

Comment: A quick answer (so take it for what it is worth): If using Windows, I have had different versions of Windows decide on their own a particular network was bad, stop communicating over it and not say a word about it.  Switching to Linux the network problems all became clear and, finally, problems could be easily solved.

Comment: Thank you, but for the server, I'm using a raspberry pi / raspbian OS running a simple Flask Server. I have actually this server for other projects and had no issues, I think the issue is that the mkr is not sending /hangs somewhere and not a case of the server not receiving since I sent requests from other sources into it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only send a data every 60s, it is better to only establish a WiFi when you need it, AND only create an instance of HttpClient after that. That's means that it only creating the `wifi` and `client` instances when you need it instead of using a global instances. Here is a way I usually do for such an application that I modified based on your sketch, you could give it a try. Please noted that only the  changes that I made are highlighted in my code snippet, please fill-in the rest of your code:

```
unsigned long INTERVAL = 60000;  // in milliseconds
unsigned long time_start = millis() + INTERVAL;    // noted that I changed this to a global variable and to unsigned long

// WiFiClient wifi;
// HttpClient client = HttpClient(wifi, serverAddress, port);

void Connecting() {
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println(" Connected");

  // your code for printing localIP
}

void loop() {
  
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    connecting();

  // send data when INTERVAL is reached
  if (millis() - time_start > INTERVAL) {
    DataMonitorAndSend();
    time_start = millis();
  }

  yield();

}

void DataMonitorAndSend() {
  // reconnecting();

  WiFiClient wifi;
  HttpClient client = HttpClient(wifi, serverAddress, port);

  // rest of your DataMinitorAndSend() code

  client.end();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that before using WiFi.begin() to re-connect, one needs to use WiFi.disconnect() first. At least that keeps my set-up reliably re-connecting, when its battery is empty or my router is out for a moment. Also, testing for WL_CONNECTED or 3 only means that one's set-up is connected to the router, but the router not necessarily yet to the internet; in case of a restart of the router after a power outage. On one of my routers, one has to wait 10 seconds, on another 18 seconds.

```
void connectToWLAN()
{
  // Check if the AirLift FeatherWing's WLAN module works
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE)
  {
    Serial.println("Connection to AirLift FeatherWing WLAN module failed");

    // If not, indicate there is a WLAN module malfunction
    WiFi.setLEDs(0, 255, 0); // Red

    // And stop forever
    while (true);
  }

  // Return to loop() if already connected to the WLAN router
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("Trying to connect to WLAN router");

  // Indicate there is no WLAN router connection just yet
  WiFi.setLEDs(192, 255, 0); // Yellow

  do
  {
    // Start connection to WLAN router and print a status value
    WiFi.disconnect();
    delay(1000);

    status = WiFi.begin(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS);
    // WL_IDLE_STATUS     = 0
    // WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL   = 1
    // WL_SCAN_COMPLETED  = 2
    // WL_CONNECTED       = 3
    // WL_CONNECT_FAILED  = 4
    // WL_CONNECTION_LOST = 5
    // WL_DISCONNECTED    = 6
    Serial.println(WiFi.status());
    delay(10000);
  }
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED);

  Serial.println("Connection to WLAN router successful");

  // Indicate that the WLAN router connection was established
  WiFi.setLEDs(255, 0, 0); // Green

  // To better see the status indicating RGB LED's state
  delay(2000);
}
```